# Understanding Tk Listbox in ruby

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to make a small program to mung some data into usable form. One thing I'd like it to do is to be able to select some files and perform actions on them, so I thought i'd use the listbox object in Tk to do that. I want to be able to open a file and see its filename displayed in the listbox. As far as I've read this is precisely what using listvariable in the listbox is for. Yet when I run my code the listbox is never updated (although items already in the listvariable variable are displayed fine).

So here's a close to MWE for this. What am I doing wrong, and what fundamental idea have I misunderstood?

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

$path_list = []
$populate_list = TkVariable.new( $path_list )

def get_file
  file = Tk.getOpenFile
  file = open(file) unless file.empty?
  path = File.basename(file, ".out")
  if $path_list.include?(path)
    Tk.messageBox(
        'type'    => "ok",
        'icon'    => "warning",
        'title'   => " - Minimum Working Example - ",
        'message' => "This file has already been added! Nothing was added to the list"
    )
  else
    $path_list.push(path)
  end
end

root = TkRoot.new {title "- Minimum Working Example -"}
frame = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(root) {padding "3 3 12 12"}.grid( :sticky => 'nsew') # 'north south east west'
TkGrid.columnconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1; TkGrid.rowconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1

$file_listbox = Tk::Listbox.new(frame) {
  listvariable $populate_list}.grid( :column => 1, :row => 0, :rowspan => 6)

Tk::Tile::Button.new(frame) {
  width 15; text 'Open file...'; command {get_file}}.grid( :column => 0, :row => 1)

Tk.mainloop
```

Do I maybe have to write it in some other order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one line of code:

```
$populate_list.value = $path_list
```

under this one:

```
$path_list.push(path)
```

It works for me, although looks weird.

`TkVariable` create a proxy for you ruby variable, thus bridge your ruby var references with Tk widgets. But i don't know why changes in proxy var don't affect the var it points to. I'm not sure whether it should do that automatically.

Comment: No it shouldn't. when you create the TkVariable, the value you pass is just the initialized value, it does not point to the other variable. So he is passing it an empty array and is initialized as such.

Comment: This is wonderful. It's been frustrating not to see how it didn't work, but this makes sense. I'm new to all of this so I guess I should get used to having to debug weird things.. Thanks